# Communication from WCF to WEB API

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I want to consume my WebAPI from my WCF Service, i.e. I want my WCF Service to call a web API. I have searched on the internet a lot, but all the forums are concentrating on calling WCF from web API, though I need the reverse of that.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Sure, it's possible to do that.  It shouldn't be any different than having an ASP.NET application or desktop application call WebAPI - there's no magic.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. Just use a normal HttpClient like you would do in any .NET application:

```
// consider caching or getting the httpclient instance from a factory
var client = new HttpClient();

//Api Base address
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

//Sending a GET request to endpoint api/products/1
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/person/1");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    //Getting the result and mapping to a Product object
    Person person = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Person>();
}
```

Since you didn't specified, the above code is for a GET request. You can find more examples here: [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client in ASP.NET Web API 2 (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

Comment: Assuming the WCF accepts Json. Not covering Soap Only WCF Services